# Can I catch events such as on Executor start in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

What I want to do, is for the executor to start a program, such as a profiling tool, when it starts (that is, before it start executing any task). In this way, it would be possible to monitor things like CPU usage of an executor. Does Spark provide such hooks/callbacks? I have used SparkListener, but that is used by the driver side. Do we have a similar thing for Executors?

Comment: No, there's nothing like that currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your requirement.
http://spark.apache.org/developer-tools.html#profiling

Setup yourkit to work with both drivers and slaves (executors). It doesn't start profiling unless you tell it. Connect to master or slave, start profiling and then run your tests.

Happy profiling!!

Comment: Seems like your solution only works for a Spark cluster. But I'm using a Yarn cluster. Any idea how to use YourKit there?

Comment: Solution in not mine! Two parts to it. (1) One copy the .so file. (2) Second pass -agentpath to the jvm. You could use spark.driver.extraJavaOptions & spark.executor.extraJavaOptions for (2). For (1) may be update the base image or use some init script.